# How to not be able to access manually /login after you logged in - VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning VueJS from an Udemy course. In the module about authentication, the instructor didn't make the whole process, so I had to try it by my self for 2 days but I succeeded 90%.

The backend is on firebase, so after login with correct data, I get back a token that I send it to local storage.

With the code that I make it, you can't see the dashboard if you are not authenticated(even you try the route manually), but what I don't like is that you can see the login page after you are authenticated(if you type /signin).

This last part is not normal to be. So if you are authenticated, when you try manually to go to /signin, you can.

In the router.js:

```
const routes = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: WelcomePage },
    { path: '/signup', component: SignupPage },
    { path: '/signin', component: SigninPage },
    { path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardPage}
  ]
});

routes.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const publicPages = ['/signin', '/signup'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('token');
  console.log(loggedIn);
  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    return next('/signin');
  }
  next();
});
```

And in store.js, inside login action:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
  router.replace("/dashboard");
}
```

Any idea what to do to /login and /register routes after login so to not be able to see them, even you manually try these routes?

If the user will try manually /signin or /signup, I want to be redirected to /dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my vue application I just use the `router.beforeEach` method with meta data plus the state of my token which I pull from my store.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      var token = store.getters.loggedIn;
      if (!token ) {
        next({
          path: '/login',
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
      if (token) {
        next({
          path: '/',
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
})
```

It checks each time the route changes.

The `requiresVisitor` meta is something I placed in my router object

```
{
    // this is can only be viewed if not logged in.
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ './views/Login.vue'),
    props: true,
    meta: {
      requiresVisitor: true,
      layout: "landing",
    },
  },
{
  // this can only be viewed if logged in.
  path: '/',
  name: 'dashboard',
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ './views/Dashboard.vue'),
  props: true,
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true,
    layout: "default",
   },
  },
```

you can read more about route guards [Here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

theses methods are typically used in the entry point to the app `main.js` or in your `router.js` file.

Comment: I tried your code, but I still can access /signin page after I logged in and I type manually /signin.

Comment: can you `console.log(token)` in the router.beforeEach method to see what is being checked in the `if(token)` condition? also did you add the meta data to your route?

Comment: Where do you recommend to put this router.beforeEach method: in main.js or in router.js ?

Comment: @dragon, I would recommend your `main.js` file because it will check each time the route is changed and will also make sure that users are unable to navigate to views without being logged in. also for views that can only be viewed while logged in should have meta data called `requiresAuth`.

Comment: @TJWeems  then what's difference between requiresAuth and requiresVisitor?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a per-route guard (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) to make the logic only run when `/signin` and `/signup` is matched, but if you want to keep it in the loop that runs over all routes you're on the right track -- you just need to invert your logic.

So what you want do is to add another if statement, checking if `isLoggedIn` is true, and that you're trying to access a public page, and in that case redirect the user to the `/dashboard` route.

```
if (!authRequired && loggedIn) {
  next('/dashboard');
  return;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help me. What I want is when I am on ```http://localhost:8080/dashboard``` and I'm logged in, if I try manually ```http://localhost:8080/signin``` I want instantly to get redirected to ```/dashboard```, because I'm logged in and is not normal to have access to that page anymore, when you are logged in.

Comment: Oh, I realize what you're looking for. I updated my answer.

Comment: Your code is good, I get redirected to /dashboard after login, I can't see the login page if I type /login, but now if I logout and I go manually to /dashboard I can see it. I tried something with beforeEnter, but doesn't work: ```{
  path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardPage, beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (store.state.token) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/signin');
    }
  }
}```

Answer (score 0):

> Best example of redirection using beforeEach

```
const routes = [
      {
        path: "/",
        name: "login",
        component: Login,
        meta:{requiresVisitor: true},
      },
      {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "dashboard",
        component: Dashboard,
        meta:{requiresVisitor: false},
      }];

    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: "history",
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes
    });

export default router;
```

> //Check the user is loged in If yes then move to next url.If not loged
>   in so move in else and check the meta and move into next other wise is
>   redirect my index url

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isLogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));
    if (isLogged) next()
    else{
      if(to.meta.requiresVisitor) next()
      else next('/')
    }
})
```